# Create multiple users using a for loop with a batch script

Tags: batch-file, command, prompt

I am trying to create multiple users and add them to local amdinistrators group using a for loop with a batch script but getting no where. I am using the following code:

```
@echo off

SET userpassword=Test@123
SET user1=bob
SET user2=peter
SET user3=john
SET user4=jack

FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,4) DO (

net %user%%i% %userpassword% /logonpasswordchg:yes /add
net localgroup Administrators %user%%i% /add

)

pause
```

Comment: remove `echo off` and look at the output.

Answer (score 3):

You need to enable delay expansion. The net command is used wrong you should try to create an account successfully before automating it. (there's a typo in there too %userpassowrd%) I think this is what you need:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set userpassword=Test@123
set user1=bob
set user2=peter
set user3=john
set user4=jack

for /l %%i in (1,1,4) do (
   net user !user%%i! %userpassword% /logonpasswordchg:yes /add
   net localgroup Administrators !user%%i! /add
)
pause
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL

SET userpassword=Test@123
SET user1=bob
SET user2=peter
SET user3=john
SET user4=jack

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,4) DO (
    net !user%%i! %userpassword% /logonpasswordchg:yes /add
    net localgroup Administrators !user%%i! /add
)
```